# Actionbar icon not showing. Items in overflow only.

Tags: android, xml, namespaces

I'm having some problems adding my own icons to the action bar. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems)  states I should be a custom namespace like this:

```
yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

but when I replace 'android' with 'com.example.appname' or even just 'appname' Android Studio give a. `'namespace out of bound error'`

Should I be making changes to one of the schemes if so where/how?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_new"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:title="@string/action_new"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
       android:title="@string/action_search"
       android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

   <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't replace it with your application name but with the actual string **`"yourapp"`**, since you define it right here:

> xmlns:**yourapp**="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto

So you don't use your application name but in this case literally `yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

Side note: you can name it something else, for example:

> xmlns:**someapp**="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto

Then the usage would be `someapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"`